# Select a certain row after a condition is true

Tags: sql

[image: Tablel]

My condition is: When the first time the status is either Open or Blocked which can be seen in Col3, take the next consecutive row only if its status is 'Closed'. If not, keeping looking until Closed appears and stop.

In the above example, The second row is what I am looking for as my output. How do I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Sure I'll be careful of that next time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the first "Close" after an "Open" or "Blocked", presumably per `Col1`.  You can use window functions for this.  A generic solution that should work in just about any database is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col4) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when col3 in ('Open', 'Blocked') then col4 end ) over (partition by col1) as first_open_blocked
            from t
           ) t
      where col3 = 'Closed' and col4 > first_open_blocked
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In Postgres, I would suggest:

```
select distinct on (col1) t.*,
from (select t.*,
             min(col4) filter (where col3) over (partition by col1) as first_open_blocked
      from t
     ) t
where col3 = 'Closed' and col4 > first_open_blocked
order by col1, col4;
```